# Benchmarking Performance

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, performance, monitoring

I'm in need to document and benchmark performance on file access between our on prem SharePoint 2010 environment and our O365 environment. I need something that can be run easily in our regions.

I was thinking of something via PowerShell, but that comes with a set of dependencies that might be difficult to manage. Perhaps some sort of console application/executable that tries to get the same file from both locations and outputs timing metrics. Or are simple tools like tracerts sufficient enough to show that one is "faster" than the other?

Essentially, how can I show/report/snapshot real time performance on file access between the two environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not very scientific or accurate, we resorted to stop watch timing of file "ready" between the cloud and local environments accessing the same set of files.